# List Workflow creates links to workflow status

Tags: workflow

Apologies if this has been asked before, I have searched and can't find a definite answer.

I have a new list in a subsite  with an associated workflow that is sending an email when an item is created. This new list/workflow combination is displaying behaviour that is not present in similar list/workflows on my other sites.

When the workflow runs it creates new columns on the associated list that contain links to the workflow status page, this does not happen on my other sites.

The only difference as far as i can tell is that my new site is using the **Team Collaboration Lists** feature.

Why is this list generating new columns with links to the Workflow Status page (WrkStat.aspx) when my other workflows do not do this? Is the Team Collaboration Lists feature adding this behaviour?